# Why is my code not executing the break statement?

Tags: java, break

I'm writing a program where I have to write back out the numbers I am given until I get the number 42.

For example:

***Input***:

```
5
6
4
42
1
0
```

***Output***

```
5
6
4
```

So far, I have tried this:

```
package com.logical01;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] array = new int[100];
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the number of elements: ");
        int n_Elements = in.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter the values now: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < n_Elements; i++) {
            array[i] = in.nextInt();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n_Elements; i++) {
            if (i == 42) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("\n"+array[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

However, this program does not work; it writes back the same values out (rather than stopping when there's a 42).

Comment: `if(i==42)` should be `if(array[i]==42)`.

Comment: Please answer this comment.. Your help was appreciated!

Comment: @MarounMaroun - hadn't seen your comment :).You could ahve posted it as an answer :)

Comment: ops beat me to it :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to change from

```
if(i == 42)
```

to

```
(if array[i] == 42)
```

`i` holds the *value* while iterating.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the loop to this:

```
for(int i=0; i<n_Elements; i++){
    if(array[i]==42){
        break;
}
```

This is because you want to iterate through the array and check if the value at index `i` is 42,

e.g. `array[4] = {1,2,42,3};`

Then the loop iterates through the array and:

`array[0] == 42 false`

`array[1] == 42 false`

`array[2] == 42 true` therefore -> `break;`